# Add xml element in a xml file using shell script

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing

i have an xml file where i need to add data, i tried using sed. Could anyone help me out where i am doing wrong.

i have an xml file like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE sf-migration
PUBLIC "-//VA Software, Inc.//DTD SourceForge Migration 1.0//EN"
"/opt/add-ons/import-6.1/dtd/sf-migration_1_0.dtd">
<sf-migration toVersion="6.1.0.0" fromVersion="5.0.0.0">
<users></users>
</sf-migration>
```

Now i need to add the below file in users :

```
<sfuser xid="user1000">
           <username>beq03838</username>
           <email>noreply@nxp.com</email>
           <alternateEmail1></alternateEmail1>
           <dateCreated>2016-12-20 14:02:23 CET</dateCreated>
           <dateLastModified>2016-12-20 14:02:23 CET</dateLastModified>
           <detail></detail>
           <monitoringPreference>email</monitoringPreference>
           <lastLogin></lastLogin>
      </sfuser>
```

And my output should be the below :

```
enter <!DOCTYPE sf-migration
PUBLIC "-//VA Software, Inc.//DTD SourceForge Migration 1.0//EN"
"/opt/add-ons/import-6.1/dtd/sf-migration_1_0.dtd">
<sf-migration toVersion="6.1.0.0" fromVersion="5.0.0.0">
<users>
<sfuser xid="user1000">
<username>beq03838</username>
<email>noreply@nxp.com</email>
<alternateEmail1></alternateEmail1>
<dateCreated>2016-12-20 14:02:23 CET</dateCreated>
<dateLastModified>2016-12-20 14:02:23 CET</dateLastModified>
<lastLogin></lastLogin>
</sfuser>
</users>
</sf-migration>
```

I use the below shell script to append the text :

```
CONTENT=give the suer content
C=$(echo $CONTENT | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
sed "/<\/users>/ s/.*/${C}\n&/" /tmptest/user1.xml
```

What am i doing wrong ? is there any other simple way to add element in xml ?
and i need this to be done in shell, as my complete code is in shell

Comment: What is the error you're getting? And is the "enter" as first word in output intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with multiple files and escaping on the command line is super error-prone and hacky. You can achieve the same with a really small script in most languages. Here's an example in Python 2:

```
template = open("user.xml").read()
snippet = open("user_data.xml").read()
result = template.replace("</users>", snippet + "</users>")
open("user.xml", "w").write(result)
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE sf-migration PUBLIC "-//VA Software, Inc.//DTD SourceForge Migration 1.0//EN" "/opt/add-ons/import-6.1/dtd/sf-migration_1_0.dtd"> <sf-migration toVersion="6.1.0.0" fromVersion="5.0.0.0">
<users>
    <sfuser xid="user1000">
           <username>beq03838</username>
           <email>noreply@nxp.com</email>
           <alternateEmail1></alternateEmail1>
           <dateCreated>2016-12-20 14:02:23 CET</dateCreated>
           <dateLastModified>2016-12-20 14:02:23 CET</dateLastModified>
           <detail></detail>
           <monitoringPreference>email</monitoringPreference>
           <lastLogin></lastLogin>
    </sfuser> 
</users>
```

---

If you need to do this more often, use this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
  print "This script prepends the given pattern in a template with a snippet. Both snippet and template are files."
  print "Usage:"
  print sys.argv[0] + " template snippet replacementpattern"
  sys.exit(1)

template = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
snippet = open(sys.argv[2]).read()
pattern = sys.argv[3]

if not pattern in template:
  print "Template doesn't contain the pattern."
  sys.exit(2)

print template.replace(pattern, snippet + pattern)
```

Usage:

```
./prepend.py template.xml snippet.xml "</users>"
```

Comment: thanks,. but in the first option that just prints the output. But i need the output of result to be saved in the source file(template)

Comment: Redirect the output to the file or use Python: `open("template.xml", "w").write(result)`

Comment: can you give me the format ?

#!/usr/bin/python

template = open("user.xml",'rw').read()

snippet = open("user_data.xml").read()

print template.replace("</users>", snippet + "</users>")


It should save the output back to the "user.xml" with the required output that print gives